# Word used for Royal title change

Tags: word-request, terminology

Presumably Queen Elizabeth 1st has only been called that title since our present Queen came to the throne, taking the title Queen Elizabeth 2nd (presumably in her lifetime Queen Elizabeth 1st would have been known as Queen Elizabeth). What is the word used to denote this change.

Comment: I don't know a specific word for it. Generally, there's _redesignation_.

Comment: I don't know a specific word for it either--Colin's suggestion of redesignation seems appropriate--but this article about regnal names may be of interest to you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnal_name

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific word or phrase for this.

You could describe this a the *redesignation* of Queen Elizabeth. A change made *retroactively*, or *in retrospect*. And you could say that the change was made to *differentiate* and  *disambiguate* between the two Queens with the same name.

Elizabeth I lived and reigned under the name "Elizabeth of England" and that remains the nearest thing there is to an official Royal name. The numeral "I" is just inserted by historians to avoid confusion.